# Import custom font in application

Tags: java, fonts, embedded-resource

I'm trying to import a local .ttf file to use it in my application, I tried this code :

```
try{
    Font font = Font.createFont(
        Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
        new File("font/FleftexM.ttf")
    ).deriveFont(24f);
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(font);
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

But don"t work, this is the architecture of my project :
[image]
[image]

Comment: "don't work" is not a problem description. What do you expect to happen, what happens instead (and if there are error messages, show those messages in your post), and why do you think it might be doing that, leading to what have you tried so far to fix the problem? (and the answers to those questions should all go in your post, not be a response comment)

Comment: Excuse me, look at the edit please.

Comment: looks like a pretty obvious error. What does your program say its current working directory is before you call the Font.createFont code?

Comment: It's working when i'm writing "res" before my path, but when i'm making a .jarof my project, he don't know the "res" directory :/ I need to import it deifferently :( Any idea ?

Comment: put the font in the base dir so it's relative to your code, and ideally write your code so that you can pass in a jar import `-d` argument to specify font path location so you can load it from the right relative location?

Comment: It's the same error :/

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Font getFont(String name) throws FontFormatException, IOException {
    String fName = "/font/" + name;
    InputStream is = FontTest.class.getResourceAsStream(fName);
    return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
}
```

This works for me with "OpenSans-Light.ttf". And also the font file is in font folder too.

Edit: `FontTest` is my class name.

Comment: Thanks, will it work if i make a .jar of my project ?

Comment: It should be no problem if the font file is in the package.